# Lock screen after starting up Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, lock-screen

I have my "Main" account and "Guest Session" account on my Ubuntu 16.04. I have my Main account password protected. So when I lock account password is needed to open it. But the issue is when PC is turned off and restarted it enters "Main" account immediately without prompting the password first. Why is that so, if my account has password protection? How can I force my Ubuntu to ask password on start up?

Comment: you probably enabled auto-login for the guest account. got to the users panel and check.

Comment: Yea. I went to User Accounts and disabled Automatic Login that was set for my Main account by default, and it seems that now it works fine, and I must enter password every time I want to enter Main account.

Comment: it is an option to set it during install as far as I can remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Zina pointed out, "Automatic Login" is probably enabled. 
For full documentation here are the steps to perform.
Click on the gear in the top right corner of the screen.
Go to "System Settings" then "User Accounts".
Click on your user.
You will see a slider labeled "Automatic Login".
Set the slider to "OFF".
If you cannot, it is probably because you need to unlock the panel in order to act as the system administrator. You need to click on the "Unlock" button and provide your user password.
You now should be able to switch the slider to "OFF".

HTH,

R. Daneel Olivaw,
The Human Robot Inside.

Comment: Yes I did this. It's a bit stupid that Automatic Login is enabled by default. I will test tomorrow if this really solves all use cases (restart/turn on/switch account)

Comment: @NordlysJeger I will after I test

Comment: I Just checked, the default in Ubuntu 16.04 & 18.04 is to ask for a password at login. If you have automatic login, it's because you selected it at install time or later on.

Comment: Aha. Maybe I selected it at install time.